The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module
I'm using batik-all 1.9.1 with Java 8.  I'm trying to update the project to Java 21, but I'm getting a "The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module" error that seems to be coming from Batik, or its transitive dependencies.
Are the later versions of batik Java 9 module friendly?  Are there release notes to see if I have to modify any code to support later versions?
